# Need help with IPhone Address book CPRecordGetStore error

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I get the following error in my IPhone crash report. I cant work out why it happens...is it possible to try and catch an EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   AppSupport                      0x304a17d8 CPRecordGetStore
1   AddressBook                     0x316f1680 ABCGetAddressBookForRecord
2   AddressBook                     0x316f5554 ABCPersonSetImageDataAndCropRectAndReturnError
3   AddressBook                     0x316f575e ABCPersonSetImageDataAndReturnError
4   AddressBook                     0x316fceb2 ABPersonSetImageData

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors are most often due to poor memory management - if you can, take a look at the call stack, and see if you can figure out if any of your objects are getting deallocated too early or released too many times.